# EF Core - When using TPH (Table Per Hierarchy), Entity Framework does not let to create foreign key relations on separate table

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have specified a user entity in DbSet and separated different user types based on discriminator. I have a table named user and in the code, I have two models named Tailor and Customer inherited from the User model. Now I want to create a table named Order which will have a tailor_id and customer_id which will have foreign key relation on user_id in the User model.

```cs
public class User
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column("user_id")]
    public long UserId { get; set; }

    [Column("user_type")]
    public string UserType { get; set; }
}

public class ShopTailor: User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Customer: User
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity), Column("order_id")]
    public long OrderId { get; set; }

    [Column("tailor_id", Order = 0)]
    public long TailorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ShopTailor Tailor { get; set; }
    
    [Column("customer_id", Order = 1)]
    public long CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

and here is my DB Context

```cs
public class TailorDbContext: DbContext, ITailorDbContext
{
    #region Ctor

    public TailorDbContext(DbContextOptions<TailorDbContext> options): base(options)
    {
    }
    #endregion

    #region DbSets

    public DbSet<ShopTailor> ShopTailors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Override Methods

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasDiscriminator(x => x.UserType)
            .HasValue<ShopTailor>(UserRoleConstants.TAILOR)
            .HasValue<Customer>(UserRoleConstants.CUSTOMER);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Tailor)
            .WithMany(t => t.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(ot => ot.TailorId)
        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
            .HasOne(o => o.Customer)
            .WithMany(c => c.Orders)
            .HasForeignKey(ct => ct.CustomerId)
    }
}
```

I have searched multiple solutions, and this is the only way to do it but still, I am getting this error

```
[18:00:10 ERR] Failed executing DbCommand (115ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
CREATE TABLE [order] (
    [order_id] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [name] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [status] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [created_date] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [due_date] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [delivery_date] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [tailor_id] bigint NOT NULL,
    [customer_id] bigint NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_order] PRIMARY KEY ([order_id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_order_user_customer_id] FOREIGN KEY ([customer_id]) REFERENCES [user] ([user_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_order_user_tailor_id] FOREIGN KEY ([tailor_id]) REFERENCES [user] ([user_id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
[18:00:11 FTL] Host terminated unexpectedly
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_order_user_tailor_id' on table 'order' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteNonQuery(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean isInternal, String endMethod)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteNonQueryAsync(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQueryAsync(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.MigrateAsync(String targetMigration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Tailor.Vendor.API.Helpers.DbMigrationHelpers.EnsureDatabasesMigratedAsync[TTailorDbContext](IServiceProvider services) in E:\Async Innovations\Tailor Application\tailor-web-app\Backend\Tailor.Vendor.API\Helpers\DbMigrationHelpers.cs:line 45
   at Tailor.Vendor.API.Helpers.DbMigrationHelpers.ApplyDbMigrationWithDataSeedAsync[TTailorDbContext](IHost host, DatabaseMigrationsConfiguration databaseMigrationsConfiguration, SeedConfiguration seedConfiguration) in E:\Async Innovations\Tailor Application\tailor-web-app\Backend\Tailor.Vendor.API\Helpers\DbMigrationHelpers.cs:line 28
   at Tailor.Vendor.API.Program.ApplyDbMigrationsWithDataSeedAsync(IConfiguration configuration, IHost host) in E:\Async Innovations\Tailor Application\tailor-web-app\Backend\Tailor.Vendor.API\Program.cs:line 110
   at Tailor.Vendor.API.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Async Innovations\Tailor Application\tailor-web-app\Backend\Tailor.Vendor.API\Program.cs:line 37
ClientConnectionId:1a98a9b1-7e76-44e6-b98f-0fc9ba694642
Error Number:1785,State:0,Class:16

E:\Async Innovations\Tailor Application\tailor-web-app\Backend\Tailor.Vendor.API\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\Tailor.Vendor.API.exe (process 120) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

P.S. I don't want to add the order entity in the User model, as I don't want the general model to be filled with extra fields which are not required by other users.